# Numpy set range where less than

Tags: numpy

```
def updatemap(depthmap, p1, p2, value):
    maps = depthmap[0:580,p1[0]:p2[0]]
    maps[maps < value] = value
    depthmap[0:580,p1[0]:p2[0]] = maps
```

This is the current way I do it. But it requires I make a copy of the range, then set the range where the value is less than, then copy it back. The copying would make it slow. Is there any syntax I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `depthmap` is a NumPy array, this part:

```
maps = depthmap[0:580,p1[0]:p2[0]]
```

doesn't actually make a copy. Unlike with lists and tuples, NumPy slicing creates a view of the original array. Thus, the next line:

```
maps[maps < value] = value
```

modifies the original `depthmap` array, and the line after that:

```
depthmap[0:580,p1[0]:p2[0]] = maps
```

is superfluous. You can just remove it:

```
def updatemap(depthmap, p1, p2, value):
    maps = depthmap[0:580,p1[0]:p2[0]]
    maps[maps < value] = value
```